# c++ - WebSocketPP multiple clients

Tags: c++, websocket

I have problem with WebSocketPP Server. I want it to handle multiple clients.
Here is my OnOpen method:

```
void Server::onOpen(
    Server* srv,
    WSServer* ws,
    websocketpp::connection_hdl& hdl)
{
    ServerPlayerTracker con;
    con.con = &hdl;
    con.protocolVersion = 0;
    con.verified = false;
    con.playerID = srv->playerCount++;
    con.roomID = 0;

    srv->players.push_back(con);
}
```

But in disconnection i have problem. I cant find what player with ID disconnected. Here is my OnClose method:

```
void Server::onClose(
    Server* srv,
    WSServer* ws,
    websocketpp::connection_hdl& hdl)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < srv->players.size(); i++)
    {
        if (srv->players[i].connected)
        {
            if ((*srv->players[i].con).lock() == hdl.lock())
            {
                printf("[!] Player disconnected with ID: %d\n", 
                    srv->players[i].playerID);
                srv->players.erase(srv->players.begin() + i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In line (*srv->players[i].con).lock() == hdl.lock() it throws exception like 
'this was 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF7.' in file 'memory' line 75. I think it's problem with converting weak_ptr to shared_ptr. Is there any way to fix that?

Comment: Take a look at: https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp/blob/master/examples/associative_storage/associative_storage.cpp

That shows how you can store data per connection.

Comment: Also take a look at the con_list described there `typedef std::map<connection_hdl,connection_data,std::owner_less<connection_hdl>> con_list;` 
`con_list m_connections;` since that may be a better implementation to save a list of connections.

Comment: thanks! problem fixed

Answer (score 1):

My comments seemed enough to fix the problem (see comments).
For future reference and to indicate that this problem has been answered, I have created this answer.

---

I'm not 100% sure what is (or is not) working in your current code, since it's quite different from the way the connections are stored and retrieved within the [example code](https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp/blob/master/examples/associative_storage/associative_storage.cpp) (See websocketPP github/documentation example "associative storage").

Using the example, it should be rather easy to set up a multiple client structure, in the way it was intended by the  library creator.

For your specific error, I believe you're on the right track about the shared/weak pointer conversion.
Best solution would be to use the list in the way it's used in the example.

Especially interesting is the "con_list" which saves all connections.
It's a `typedef` of `std::map<connection_hdl,connection_data,std::owner_less<conn‌​ection_hdl>> con_list; con_list m_connections;` and should enable you to store and retrieve connections (and their session data).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now i use set for connection_handler-s and vector for PlayerTrackers. Each PlayerTracker contains it's connection_handler's iterator and it works. But i dont think it's good way.

Comment: What do you mean with "PlayerTrackers"? Have you checked on how to use session storage? You can simply add data (or a reference to an player object) in your per session data.